# 'Any' filter doesn't seem to work for specific synonyms of specific tags

Tags: bug, new-nav

Using tags [c++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), [c++14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) and selecting `any`, I get those questions

[image]

When replacing [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) with [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) (which is a synonym of [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z)), I get those questions

[image]

I get the same questions if I select `all`

[image]

Why does using [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with `any` filter show the same questions as using [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z)/[c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) with `all` filter?

Comment: That's unexpected.  I can reproduce on Chrome 51.